# Running automated jobs in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, continuous-integration, pgadmin-4

I have setup a PostgreSQL server and am using PgAdmin 4 for managing the databases/clusters. I have a bunch of SQL validation scripts (.sql) which I run on the databases every time some data is added to the database.

My current requirement is to automatically run these .sql scripts and generate some results/statistics every time new data is added to any of the tables in the database.

I have explored the use of pg_cron (https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/09/09/pgcron-run-periodic-jobs-in-postgres/) and pgAgent (https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/pgagent_jobs.html)

Before I proceed to integrate any of these tools into my application, I wanted to know if it is advisable to proceed using these utilities or if I should employ the service of a full-fledged CI framework like Jenkins?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either pg_cron or pgAgent. But your requirement sounds like a trigger might be the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz, do you know how to run a trigger when some data is added to any of the tables in the database?

Comment: A quick web search will turn up thousands of hits. But take it from the documentation: [general behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html) and [how to write them in PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: pgAdmin4 fully supports pgAgent.